# ERROR: Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter while trying to login with credentials

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to login to the application I gave the right credentials in Sql database but it is showing "No such account exists, Please insert valid credentials". The login table in sql have four parameters id,role,username,password(which is bycrypted).The id and username have same values.
[image]

The error in console is:

```
Hibernate: select login0_.username as username1_2_, login0_.id as id2_2_, login0_.password as password3_2_, login0_.role as role4_2_ from Login login0_ where login0_.role=? and login0_.username=?
Hibernate: {call users_in_system(?,?,?,?)}
Oct 13, 2023 9:29:34 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
Oct 13, 2023 9:29:34 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter
```

LoginView.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" import="com.project.dao.LoginDao" 
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
     <%! 
    LoginDao infoLog= new LoginDao();
    %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>User Log In</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="signup-form">
    <form action="dashboard.html" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <h2>Sign In</h2>
        <p>Please fill in this form to access your account!</p>
        <hr>
        
        <div class="form-group" style="color: red;">
            <%  
            try{
                String status=(String)request.getAttribute("status");
                infoLog.logActivities("loginview: "+status);
                    if(status.equals("false"))
                    {  out.print("No such account exists. Please insert valid credentials");  }
                }
            catch(Exception e)
                {infoLog.logActivities("loginview: "+e);}
            %>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="role">Role</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="role" id="exampleSelect1">
            <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
            <option value="receptionist">Receptionist</option>
            <option value="administrator">Administrator</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Username"
          required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password"
          required="required">
        </div>
        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
        
        
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.project.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.project.dao.LoginDao;
import com.project.entity.Login;

@Controller
public class LoginController 
{
    @Autowired
    LoginDao dao;
    
    @Autowired
    PatientPrescriptionDao dao1;
    
    @Autowired
    UsersInSystemDao dao2;
     
    @RequestMapping(value="/login.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView view()
    {
        try
        {
            ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView();
            mv.setViewName("LoginView");
            mv.addObject("status", "true");
            return mv;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            dao.logActivities("LoginController-view: "+e);  
            ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView();
            mv.setViewName("failure");
            mv.addObject("error",e);
            return mv;
        }
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/dashboard.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView validate(@RequestParam("role")String role, @RequestParam("username")String username, @RequestParam("password")String password, HttpServletRequest request ) 
    {
        try {
            //validation code
            dao.logActivities("in LoginController-validate:got= "+role+" "+username+" "+password);
            Login l1=new Login(null,role, username, password);
            
            String userId=dao.validate(l1); //call to LoginDao
            dao.logActivities("returned to logincontroller-validate:got= "+userId);

                if (!userId.equals(null))
                {   
                    //setting session
                     HttpSession session= request.getSession();
                     Login l=new Login(userId,l1.getRole(),l1.getUsername(),null);
                     session.setAttribute("userInfo", l);
                     dao.logActivities(session.getId());
                     for(Integer i: dao2.getUsersInSystem()) {
                         dao.logActivities(i.toString());
                     }
                                         
                     //display dashboard
                    ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView();                
                    mv.setViewName("welcome");
                    mv.addObject("prescriptionsCount", dao1.prescriptionPrintCount());  //for receptionist only
                    mv.addObject("users_count", dao2.getUsersInSystem());  //for admin only
                    return mv;
                }
                else
                {   throw new Exception();  }
                
                }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                dao.logActivities("LoginController-validate: "+e);  
                ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView();
                mv.setViewName("LoginView");
                mv.addObject("status", "false");
                return mv;
            }
    } 
    
}
```

LoginDao.java

```
package com.project.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.project.entity.Login;

@Component
public class LoginDao 
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sf;  //hibernate configuration in springMVC-servlet.xml file
    
    @Autowired
    LoginDao infoLog;
    
    //to manage transaction by itself
    @Transactional
    public String validate(Login l)
    {
        try 
        {
            infoLog.logActivities("in logindao-validate:got= "+l);
                            
            Session session= sf.getCurrentSession();
            Query q1=session.createQuery("from Login where role= :r AND username= :u");
            q1.setParameter("r", l.getRole());
            q1.setParameter("u", l.getUsername());
        
            Login temp= (Login) q1.uniqueResult();
            boolean validUser=BCrypt.checkpw(l.getPassword(),temp.getPassword());
            infoLog.logActivities("in logindao-validate:found= "+"i/p="+l.getPassword()+", db="+temp.getPassword()+", match= "+validUser);
            if(!validUser)
            { 
                throw new Exception("Password didn't matched"); 
            }
            return temp.getId();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            infoLog.logActivities("in logindao-validate: "+e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public void logActivities(String s)
    {
        //System.out.println("@"+s);
    }
    
}
```

SpringMVC-servlet.xml

```
<!-- to specify folder and extension for view files -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
        
            
<!-- Hibernate configuration started     -->

    <!-- properties for connection i.e. jdbc pooling ,datasource has database info -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
<!--        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> -->
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="MY_DB_PASSWORD" />
        
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="3" />
<!--        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />   min 5 connections -->
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>
    
    <!-- sessionFactory object  -->
    <!-- LocalSessionFactoryBean :gives object of sessionFactory -->
    <!-- dataSource :is the above bean id which specifies jdbc pooling properties -->
    <!-- packagesToScan :location (package) of all entity classes -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.project.entity" />   <!--it specifies path to scan for annotated entity classes or <property name=""> <value></value> </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>  <!-- language used to create queries for DB -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  <!-- to see queries in console -->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> <!--  action to be performed with database on start-up -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- transactions will be done using annotations -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />
    
    <!--  -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" >
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20mb -->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me it look like hibernate is making the select.

Hibernate: `select login0_.username as username1_2_, login0_.id as id2_2_, login0_.password as password3_2_, login0_.role as role4_2_ from Login login0_ where login0_.role=? and login0_.username=?`

And then for some reason it trigger procedure
Hibernate: `{call users_in_system(?,?,?,?)}`

I think for this procedure you are getting: `Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter`

Investigate if you need this procedure and how you invoke it. I do not see to be called in the code. You can show the Entity class.